# Get the parent of a List Item

Tags: list, client-object-model

Given the following information;

```
string webUrl, Guid listId, int itemIdInList
```

I'm trying to retrieve the parent of this item, whether that is a List or another ListItem (i.e. a folder).

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to achieve this? The list part isn't too bad, but there isn't much information online regarding the retrieval of parent folder IDs.

Answer (score 1):

C. McAtackney,

What you can do is make SPQuery object for querying list items and

```
 query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
```

Once you get list items, you can get the folder path from list item url. 
SPUtility.GetUrlDirectory will give you the URL directory, which consists of the folder hierarchy. Using this information you can retrieve the parent folder.

```
string dirPath = SPUtility.GetUrlDirectory(item.Url);  
 if (dirPath != null)  
 {  
     string[] dirs = dirPath.Split(new char[] { '/' });  
     if (dirs.Length > 0)  
    {  
       return (dirs[dirs.Length - 1]);  
    }   
 }
```

And if you want to see whether the current Item is itself a Folder Content Type or a List Item, you can do something like this:

```
if (lstItem.ContentTypeId == SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Folder)
if (lstItem.ContentTypeId == SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Item)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Arsalan, thanks for your response. I'm using the Client Object Model, so I don't believe I have access to SPUtility - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you will not have SPUtility in Client OM.. Sorry, I didn't read that!

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri, helped me though :-)

Comment: Good to know :-)

Comment: RecursiveAll should include the folders in the initial query, right?

Comment: `RecursiveAll` brings all folders, all subfolders and all files within the folders and subfolders (everything)